# co_await appears to be suboptimal?

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

I have an async function

```
void async_foo(A& a, B& b, C&c, function<void(X&, Y&)> callback);
```

I want to use it in a stackless coroutine so I write

```
auto coro_foo(A& a, B& b, C& c, X& x) /* -> Y */ {
  struct Awaitable {
    bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }
    bool await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> h) {
      async_foo(*a_, *b_, *c_, [this, h](X& x, Y& y){
        *x_ = std::move(x);
        y_ = std::move(y);
        h.resume();
      });
    }
    Y await_resume() {
      return std::move(y);
    }
    A* a_; B* b_; C* c_; X* x_; Y y_;
  };
  return Awaitable{&a, &b, &c, &x};
}
```

then I can use it like this:

```
Y y = co_await coro_foo(a, b, c, x);
```

and compiler would rewrite it to this:

```
  auto e = coro_foo(a, b, c, x);
  if (!e.await_ready()) {
    <suspend>
    if (e.await_suspend(h)) return;
resume-point:
    <resume>
  }
  Y y = e.await_resume();
```

With this, the coroutine would keep `a_`, `b_`, and `c_` when it's suspended, when it only have to keep them until we get `coroutine_handle` in `await_suspend(h)`.
(Btw I'm not sure if I can keep references to the arguments here.)

It would be much more efficient if the wrapper function could directly get `coroutine_handle` as an argument.

It could be an implicit argument:

```
Promise f(coroutine_handle<> h);
co_await f();
```

Or it could be a special keyword-argument:

```
Promise f(coroutine_handle<> h);
f(co_await);
```

Am I missing something here? (Other that the overhead is not that big.)

Comment: my library, concurrencpp, really handles futures and coroutines beautifully, in very optimized way, check it out: https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp

Comment: @DavidHaim and how do I use it with existing API like `asio::async_read` or `WSARecv`? Btw, you might wanna update it, `initial_suspend` can't return bool.

Comment: you will have to write a wrapper that passes a `concurrencpp::promise` to any `boost::async_xxx` and return a `concurencpp::future`. then you use regular `co_await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current design has an important future that `co_await` takes a general expression and not a call expression.

This allows us to write code like this:

```
auto f = coro_1();
co_await coro_2();
co_await f;
```

We can run two or more asynchronous tasks in-parallel, and then wait for both of them.

Consequently, the implementation of `coro_1` should start its work in its call, and not in `await_suspend`.

This also means that there should be a pre-allocated memory where `coro_1` would put its result, and where it would take the `coroutine_handle`.

We can use non-copyable `Awaitable` and guaranteed **copy elision**.
`async_foo` would be called from constructor of `Awaitable`:

```
auto coro_foo(A& a, B& b, C& c, X& x) /* -> Y */ {
  struct Awaitable {
    Awaitable(A& a, B& b, C& c, X& x) : x_(x) {
      async_foo(a, b, c, [this](X& x, Y& y){
        *x_ = std::move(x);
        y_ = &y;
        if (done_.exchange(true)) {
          h.resume();  // Coroutine resumes inside of resume()
        }
      });
    }
    bool await_ready() const noexcept {
      return done_;
    }
    bool await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> h) {
      h_ = h;
      return !done_.exchange(true);
    }
    Y await_resume() {
      return std::move(*y_);
    }
    atomic<bool> done_;
    coroutine_handle<> h_;
    X* x_;
    Y* y_;
  };
  return Awaitable(a, b, c, &x);
}
```

Comment: Looks like heap corruption, because after returning from coro_func, Awaitable object that was captured (by this) inside lambda is destructed. Probably need to use enable_ptr_from_this...but except this small issue, this is great.

Comment: There is only one `Awaitable`, no copies or moves. `Awaitable` even contains an `atomic`, to stress the point.

Answer (score 3):

The "coroutine" system defined by the Coroutine TS is designed to handle asynchronous functions which:

1. Return a future-like object (an object which represents a delayed return value).
2. The future-like object has the ability to be associated with a continuation function.

`async_foo` doesn't fulfill these requirements. It doesn't return a future-like object; it "returns" a value via a continuation function. And this continuation is passed as a parameter, rather than being something you do with the object's return type.

By the time the `co_await` happens at all, the potentially asynchronous process that generated the future is expected to have already *started*. Or at least, the `co_await` machinery makes it *possible* for it to have started.

Your proposed version loses out on the `await_ready` feature, which is what allows `co_await` to handle potentially-asynchronous processes. Between the time the future is generated and `await_ready` is called, the process may have finished. If it has, there is no need to schedule the resumption of the coroutine. It should therefore happen right here, on this thread.

If that minor stack inefficiency bothers you, then you would have to do things the way the Coroutine TS wants you to.

The general way to handle this is where `coro_foo` would directly execute `async_foo` and return a future-like object with a `.then`-like mechanism. Your problem is that `async_foo` itself doesn't have a `.then`-like mechanism, so you have to create one.

That means `coro_foo` must pass `async_foo` a functor that stores a `coroutine_handle<>`, one that can be updated by the future's continuation mechanism. Of course, you'll also need synchronization primitives. If the handle has been initialized by the time the functor has been executed, then the functor calls it, resuming the coroutine. If the functor completes without resuming a coroutine, the functor will set a variable to let the await machinery know that the value is ready.

Since the handle and this variable is shared between the await machinery and the functor, you'll need to ensure synchronization between the two. That's a fairly complex thing, but it's whatever `.then`-style machinery requires.

Or you could just live with the minor inefficiency.

Comment: `await_ready` is for synchronous results (e.g. a cached result, or an invalid argument error). If a parallel thread finishes the asynchronous task in-between `auto e = f();` and `e.await_ready();` then something went wrong.

Comment: @Abyx: "*then something went wrong*" It's threaded code; "going wrong" can be something as simple as "your thread went to sleep unexpectedly for a while, and the other process was really short." A functional threading system *must* be able to handle all such eventualities. Quick forward progress is not guaranteed and *must not* be assumed. And `co_await` is designed to be able to handle such cases.

Comment: Many existing APIs use callbacks. (Every C API,  OS APIs included). Why stick to futures which would be built on top of those callback-based primitives, with additional synchronization?

Comment: @Abyx: Perhaps you noticed that the return type of a coroutine is some form of "future", and that the coroutine machinery includes internally creating a "promise" for the coroutine function that is used to communicate to that "future" return value. The promise/future paradigm is *all over* the Coroutines TS design; that's what it's meant to work with. That paradigm allows multiple levels of coroutines and continuations *without* having every level explicitly take functions to call.

Comment: So I want to rewrite an HTTP server to coroutines, but alas it uses `epoll` and apparently I need to ask Linux developers to write me another API which would be compatible with coroutines and work with the same performance because I want the server with coroutines, not a 10% slower server with coroutines.

Comment: @Abyx: Why do you believe that a few stack variables will cause your code to be "10% slower"? I suspect that whatever performance cost that would entail (on the order of *nano*-seconds) would be dwarfed by the cost of networking (on the order of *milli*-seconds).

Comment: Future is a shared state, mutex, storage for result and callback. Normally there would be an allocation on heap, and spinlock on mutex. Networking - non-blocking IO - doesn't cost much, it's only a switch to kernel-mode and back.

Answer (score 1):

`async_foo` could be called directly from `coro_foo` if we use a future-like class.
It would cost us a single allocation and an atomic variable:

```
static char done = 0;

template<typename T>
struct Future {
  T t_;
  std::atomic<void*> addr_;

  template<typename X>
  void SetResult(X&& r) {
    t_ = std::move(r);
    void* h = addr_.exchange(&done);
    if (h) std::experimental::coroutine_handle<>::from_address(h).resume();
  }

  bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }
  bool await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h) noexcept {
    return addr_.exchange(h.address()) != &done;
  }
  auto await_resume() noexcept {
    auto t = std::move(t_);
    delete this;  // unsafe, will be leaked on h.destroy()
    return t;
  }
};

Future<Y>& coro_foo(A& a, B& b, C& c, X& x) {
  auto* p = new Future<Y>;
  async_foo(a, b, c, [p, &x](X& x_, Y& y_) {
        x = std::move(x_);
        p->SetResult(y_);
  });
  return *p;
}
```

It doesn't look very expensive,
but it doesn't significantly improve the code in the question.
(It also hurts my eyes)

Comment: "*It also hurts my eyes*" Then don't look at it ;) I'm being somewhat serious. Tuck that `Future<T>` implementation into a header somewhere, and just use it when you need it. The good part of `co_await` is that it makes asynchronous code *appear* synchronous. And when you actually use `co_await` with `coro_foo` (which is what you'll be looking at 99% of the time), your code will have the apparent logic of synchronous operation while actually being asynchronous.