# C++ : Is it possible to pass a pointer of coroutine object to another function inside the coroutine itself?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine, c++-experimental, c++-ts

In case my phrasing wasn't clear, here's the code.

```
struct token {};

struct resumable {
    struct promise_type {
        auto get_return_object() {
            return coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this);
        }
        suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        suspend_always final_suspend() { return {}; }

        auto await_transform(token)
        {
            struct awaiter {
                awaiter(promise_type& p) : m_promise(p) {}
                bool await_ready() { return false; }
                void await_suspend(coroutine_handle<>) {}
                int await_resume() {
                    int _result = 5;
                    return _result;
                }
                promise_type& m_promise;
            };
            return awaiter(*this);
        }
    };

    bool resume() {
        if (!m_handle.done()) {
            m_handle.resume();
        }
        return !m_handle.done();
    }

    resumable(coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) : m_handle(h) {}

private:
    coroutine_handle<promise_type> m_handle;
};

void someAsyncKernelApi(void* callbackContext)
{
    // When async work is done, enqueues callbackContext into the completion queue.
}

token WrappedAsyncKernelApi(void* callbackContext)
{
    someAsyncKernelApi(callbackContext);
    return token{};
}

resumable coro()
{
    int _async_result = co_await WrappedAsyncKernelApi(/* Is it possible to pass address of this own 
                                                          spawned coroutine to get called later on? 
                                                          Same address the pointer "r_ptr" at main 
                                                          is pointing to*/);
}

int main()
{
    resumable* r_ptr = new auto(coro());
}
```

Few solutions I can think of right now are either initial suspend when the coroutine is spawned and store the pointer in an arbitrary struct and pass from that stored struct, or awaiting a resumable pointer on first await.
But I feel like there's much cleaner way to do this.. Is there any?

Comment: It's not really clear what it is you're trying to accomplish with this. You seem to have some API that takes... something that will be "enqueued" into a "completion queue". What does that mean? This whole thing seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas In a nutshell, the question was if there's any easier way to obtain a "this" pointer in coroutine body like how classes do inside their member function body.

Comment: Create a custom awaitable: `auto WrappedAsyncKernelApi() { struct awaiter : suspend_always { void await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> handle) { someAsyncKernelApi(handle); } }; return awaiter{}; }` Now you can `co_await WrappedAsyncKernelApi()`.

Comment: @JeremyHansen: And my question is why are you trying to obtain a this pointer at all? The `co_await` feature is designed to work in a very specific way, and extracting a handle and passing it around within the coroutine *is not that way*. I can't correct your code unless you explain what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish. [This could be your problem/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45311488/734069), but without understanding what's going on, I don't know how to help.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's elegant. Thanks.
Just to be sure, did you mean to suggest passing it by `handle.address()` instead of handle itself and later casting it back from `coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_address(obtained_ptr)` function?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, forgot that `someAsyncKernelApi` wants a `void*`. Use `.address()` and `from_address()` to convert back and forth.

Comment: @NicolBolas I omitted the details on purpose to not overwhelm the post but here are more details.
When calling async functions to the C-style kernel call, (e.g. 'async_read', 'async_send', 'async_accept' variant)
they usually communicate through 'void*' contextPointer to let the user later decide what work needs to be done in the thread pool (threads that wait on completion queue and dequeues from it when the async call completes) after completion/failure of the posted async operation.

Comment: @NicolBolas So I thought passing a "this" coroutine pointer and resume that coroutine from a completion handling thread would be the most simplistic approach hence why I tried to obtain a "this" pointer of the coroutine.